# Book series with a warrior woman from the past taken to the future to compete in a series of challenges

Tags: story-identification, books

In the future everyone wears these suits that work with psi power. This man tries to frustrate the woman from the past to get her psi power to kick in. He decides to try sexual frustration.

Her best friend turns out to be a computer with a female personality who is in love with a pilot, so in book two she creates a body and transfers her consciousness into it so she can win him over.

There is a total of 4 books in the series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Rystani Warrior* (2004-2017) by Susan Kearney, four books and a short (novella?).

Summary of the first book, *The Challenge*, from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/729576.The_Challenge):

> A hunk named Kahn, who told Secret Service agent Tessa Camen an outlandish story about traveling through time, saving the world, and a Challenge only she can accept. **Kahn offers her proof she can't refute: Tessa has been brought forward through time to save Earth by winning an intergalactic challenge.**
>
> **Kahn only has a few weeks to train Tessa to use the psi-abilities he insists she has. He is confident in the success of a time-honored method that uses sexual frustration to bring out her powers**, but Tessa is dubious. She's a martial arts expert and can fight her way through anything, but she's never had much luck with emotions.
>
> Luckily for Earth, Kahn can be very convincing...

And in the second book, *The Dare*, still from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1020948.The_Dare):

> Specifically, Dora wants to make love with the handsome Rystani warrior-pilot Zical. But since Dora is a computer-albeit a sentient computer-she cannot experience touch, taste and true desire. Dora's logic functions refuse to accept this, so **she uses the advanced technology of the 24th century to build herself a body specifically crafted to appeal to Zical, and downloads her computer brain into it.**

---

Found with the Google query `book series warrior woman suit psi power`.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. I tried everything in my google search except psi power.

Comment: @AngelGrant you're welcome, enjoy the re-read!